# WCF: Is there a way to remove ExtensionData field?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I just started using WCF and I already came to a project-altering issue. I created a service and put in reference in a webservice, but the every field in the webservice xml file comes with an ExtensionData field.

Example:

*removed dead ImageShack link*

I don't want this. I need it to be only:

*removed dead ImageShack link*

Is there a way to remove this field? Some different kind of serialization?

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What do you mean "every field in the ... xml file"? XML files don't have fields. Where do you see ExtensionData, and why is it a problem?

Answer (score 10):

The ExtensionData is actually a feature that must be built into the type to enable [round-tripping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731083.aspx). It is always emitted by the DataContractSerializer. One possible way of *suppressing* this field is using the older XmlSerializer by decorating your service contract interface with the [XmlSerializerFormatAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.xmlserializerformatattribute.aspx).

Comment: this is stupid because if you're trying to compare the object for a PUT and make sure the same object is coming back, your unit tests fail due to this stupid field having data in the response but not in the request

Comment: @MSSucks maybe your unit tests should be checking properties statically and not via late or runtime binding?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, your DataContract classes will be implementing the `IExtensibleDataObject` interface, right? That's responsible for the `ExtensionData` field - just remove that interface, and you should be able to remove the `ExtensionData` fields, too, from your DataContracts.

Marc

Comment: But the interface is implicit, so how can you remove it ?

Answer (score 3):

Setting the property to `null` prevent it to appear in the resulting xml :

```
foreach(var elem in arrayOfElements)
{
    elem.ExtensionData = null;
}
```

Comment: As much as I don't like using hacks, this was a very quick (temporary) solution. +1

Answer (score 2):

ExtensionData is used to maintain compatibility across services that may share contracts of different versions.  It can be safely ignored when passing messages.

You may be able to get rid of it by using something other than the DataContract serializer (im thinking old school [Serializable]), but i could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering the question, but maybe this helps...

From MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731083.aspx:

The round-tripping feature may be turned off, either by setting ignoreExtensionDataObject to true in the DataContractSerializer constructor or by setting the IgnoreExtensionDataObject property to true on the ServiceBehaviorAttribute. When this feature is off, the deserializer will not populate the ExtensionData property, and the serializer will not emit the contents of the property.

Comment: Setting the value to true doesn't make the ExtensionData property disappear; it just prevents sending data, if any exists, to the client.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is in an assertion of a [TestMethod] you can use http://www.fluentassertions.com to exclude every ExtensionData properties from your assertions.

Eg.

```
objToCheck.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expectedObj, options => options.Excluding(o => o.ExtensionData));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Your class should not inherit IExtensibleDataObject.

Please refer to the description of the Round-tripping below:

The Round-tripping occurs when data is transferred from a new version to an old version and transferred to the new version of the data contract. Bypass ensures that no data is lost. Turning off bypass makes the type ahead compatible with any future changes supported by the contract version model.

To enable trip-tripping for a particular type, the type should execute the

> IExtensibleDataObject

interface.

The user interface contains an ExtensionData (ExtensionDataObject) attribute. The property stores any information from future versions of the data contract that is unknown to the current version.

Answer (score -1):

decorate your ServiceImplementation with [ServiceBehavior(IgnoreExtensionDataObject=true)]

```
[ServiceBehavior(IgnoreExtensionDataObject=true)]
public class Service : IService {}
```